# Remove words from string if they're NOT in a c# dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, calculator

I'm currently making a simple calculator app just to get my skills up, although I'm trying to do it in an advanced way... Here is the dictionary:

```
operators = new Dictionary<string, string>(50);
```

I then add operators like:

```
operators.add(plus, "+");
```

this all works fine but if there is something in the string I parse into it such as `5 x 6` instead of `5 * 6` it will fail. So my question is how do I remove all words from a string that are not in the dictionary?

Thanks

P.S. I'm building a mathparser so I use it like:

```
Mathparser.Parse("5 * 6");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = "5 x 3".Where(c => !operators.ContainsValue(c.ToString())).ToArray();
string NotInDictionary = new string(s);
```

Not sure where you are going with this though... can't you just replace "x" with "*"?

Comment: Thanks but I got two errors: `Cannot convert from dictionary to char` and `dictionary does not contain a value for Contains` which is a little odd.

Comment: @Swenflea Did you add "using System.Linq;" to your usings?

Comment: thanks but it only semi-works... for example if the string was `5 somerandom text that needs to be removed x 3` I need it to output `5*3` thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: sorry, input is `5 somerandom text that needs to be removed * 3` and output `5*3`